# React problem with getting image from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently practicing React, and my goal is to build a simple app that searches movies and display some short info about them as results. I managed to pull data from API and store em in React hooks. I can access any data, but when I try to pull images I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of null.

Here are the API results:
http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=$girls

I find an image that I want to use stored in {show.image.medium}

Here is my React code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Movie from './Movie';

const App = () => {

const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getMovies();
}, []);

const getMovies = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=$girls`);
  const data = await response.json();
  setMovies(data);
  console.log(data)

  ;}
  return (
    <div>
    <form className='search-form'>
    <input type='text' className='search-bar' placeholder='search movie'>
    </input>
    <button type='submit' className='search-button'>
    Search
    </button>
    </form>
    {movies.map(movie => (
      <Movie title={movie.show.name} image={movie.show.image.medium} />
    ))}
    </div>
  );
};



export default App;
```

and Movie.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

const Movie = ({title, image}) => {
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <img src={image} alt=''/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Movie;
```

so I basically mapped the results in **movie** array, but {movie.show.image.medium} just won't work, while pulling any other data work just fine.

I know that this is probably an easy fix, but I tried everything and searched for an answer for hours and still, nothing worked. I would really appreciate it if someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that every movie has an **image** field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the API call there is one value where `movie.show.image` is technically `null`. For `null` you could not get any properties, even `medium`.

What you can do as a solution is the following:

```
{
   movies.map(movie =>
              movie.show.image ?
                  <Movie title={movie.show.name} image={movie.show.image.medium} /> :
              null)
}
```

Additionally you need to `return` from [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Iteration from the API on my `console`:

[image: sceenshot]

I hope that helps!